# Pathfinder 5-foot step vs. D&D 4e shift

Tags: dnd-4e, pathfinder-1e, movement

Is a 5-foot step in Pathfinder essentially the same as a Shift movement in D&D 4th edition? I believe that neither movements provoke an attack of opportunity so they sound like the same thing with a different name.

From ["Take 5-Foot Step", Combat, *PFSRD*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Take-5-Foot-Step):

> You can move 5 feet in any round when you don't perform any other kind of movement. Taking this 5-foot step never provokes an attack of opportunity. You can't take more than one 5-foot step in a round, and you can't take a 5-foot step in the same round that you move any distance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Mostly**

Pathfinder's (and 3.5's) "5-foot step" move action is almost the same as 4e's "shift" move action. Both let you move one (5-foot) square without provoking any OA/AoO attacks.

Note that there are 2 differences: in 4e, shifting can be one half of a double move, but in 3.5/Pathfinder it cannot, since in 3.5/Pathfinder you can't take a 5-foot step in the same round that you move any distance (other than the 5-foot step). The other difference is that in 3.5/Pathfinder, taking a 5-foot doesn't use up your move action for the round (or any other actions for that matter), so you can still use it for non-movement purposes (such as a full-attack).

Comment: Thats what I thought. Thank you for confirming it for me.

Comment: 5-foot step in Pathfinder is a free action even, meaning it doesn't take up any of your actions (thinking of swift for example).

Comment: Note that this difference doesn't mean you can't safely withdraw in 3.5 (or PF, AFAIK).  If all you do in a round is move, you do not provoke AoO from leaving the initial square of movement.  If you wish to withdraw, then, you simply don't take a 5-foot step.

Answer (score 11):

## Sort of, but not really.

A 4th edition shift is similar in that you can **spend a move action to shift*** one square without provoking an opportunity attack, but the similarities end there.

<sup>*this is the closest thing to a 5-foot step, you can't just say "a shift"</sup>

While any character can use a move action *to* shift 1 square, there is no direct analogy between a shift and a 5-foot step, and they are certainly not "the same thing with a different name."

Take the following examples that clearly deviate from 3.5/pathfinder

- You can shift twice or more in one turn
- You can take your normal movement, and then shift, or do so in reverse order.
- There are powers that let you shift multiple squares at a time

---

The best way to think of shifting is that it is **an amount of movement that does not provoke opportunity attacks**, with the additional clarification that any character can spend a move action to shift one square.

Comment: one of your bullet points is incorrect. There are pathfinder feats that trigger on 5-foot steps. 'Step up' being one.

Comment: @ColinD Thanks, I did not remember anything like that from my 3.5 days. Removed that point.